# Join in cakephp not showing all the data

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to have this query

```
SELECT * FROM `rentprograms` AS `Rentprogram` 
    inner join `vehiclerentprograms` as  `Vehiclerentprogram` on `Vehiclerentprogram`.`rentprogramid` = `Rentprogram`.`id` 
    inner join `vehicles` AS `Vehicle` ON `Vehicle`.`id` =`Vehiclerentprogram`.`vehicleid` WHERE `Vehicle`.`id` = 1
```

Code in CakePHP

```
$this->Rentprogram->find('all'), array(
  'fields'=>array('*'),
  'joins' => array(
      array(
        'table' => 'vehiclerentprograms',
                'alias' => 'Vehiclerentprogram',
                'type'=>'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Vehiclerentprogram.rentprogramid' => 'Rentprogram.id',
                                )
                            ),
                array(
                'table' => 'vehicles',
                'alias' => 'Vehicle',
                'type'=>'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Vehicle.id' => 'Vehiclerentprogram.vehicleid',
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                    );
```

But it only display the value of Rentprogram. How can i have all the fields related to Rentprogram, Vehicle, Vehiclerentprogram.

Answer (score 1):

There's no value in using an MVC framework and do the *dirty joins* by hand. You'd better use Cake conventions, which lets you access Cake's libraries and tools which in turn speed up the development process quite a lot. In this case you have to setup *models* and *associations* between models (I hope you have heard of *has-many*, *belongs-to*, *many-to-many* and so on).

CakePHP ships with an invaluable DAO layer and a code generator called *bake*. Once you design the database schema, forget about SQL and think in terms of your business objects. First, create three tables in MySQL (I used a minimal set of fields and deduced the structure from your query):

```
CREATE TABLE `programs` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `vehicle_programs` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `program_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then run the shell script:

```
Console/cake bake all
```

and select one table at a time (remember `vehicle_programs` must be the last one). This will generate all Models, Controllers and Views files for you. Then you can start filling your database with test data. Point your browser to `http://host/vehicle_programs` and put some vehicle and program in.

Finally I will show you how to retrieve all of the fields in one query. Suppose that you want to show everything when listing `vehicle_programs`. In the `index()` method of `VehicleProgramsController` you have to set `$this->VehicleProgram->recursive` to `1`, so that it fetches related models fields as well. In the view `index.ctp` you'll now be able to access fields like

```
<?php
foreach ($vehiclePrograms as $vehicleProgram) {
  echo $vehicleProgram['Program']['start'];
  echo $vehicleProgram['VehicleProgram']['id'];
  echo $vehicleProgram['Vehicle']['plate'];
}
```

Note if we hadn't set `Model->recursive` to `1`, Cake wouldn't have fetched fields of related models (`Vehicle` and `Program`) for us.

---

Incidentally, I think not setting the `fields` key at all should do the trick, since Cake reads everything by default. However, the correct solution is using relationships between model classes - when you run `bake` it puts the following in `Model/Vehicle.php`:

```
class Vehicle extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'VehicleProgram' => array(
            'className' => 'VehicleProgram',
            'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );

}
```

and symmetric associations in `Model/VehicleProgram.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
$this->Rentprogram->find('all'), array(
 'fields' => array('Rentprogram.*', 'Vehicle.*', 'Vehiclerentprogram.*'), ...
```